# Can't make Application.DisplayAlerts = False in Excel 2016 VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have been chasing my tail for weeks, with more hours "Googling around than I want to admit.

I have a large, complex analytical app within an Excel 2016 spreadsheet that captures SQL table data, queries email data and does a lot of stuff that I think is pretty cool.  Users see sales force automation performance metrics and charts.  All is well except for one thing.  I cannot stop the "save data?" dialog box from appearing no matter what I do.

As a workaround I've put the spreadsheet on on a network ride and given users a shortcut that runs a VBscript to copy this spreadsheet to a hidden drive on the local PC and runs it.  So if they save it, there's no worries as they aren't working with the original data.  But as one would easily imagine, the load time is necessarily longer than it need be and users are confused by a message when I am telling them they can't save the data.

Net of a lot of different experiments, it seems like I've uncovered a bug in Excel (yeah, I know, this sounds lame even to me) as I cannot make the Application.DisplayAlerts = False.  It just will not take.

See image here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFx68.png)

The image above (or at the above link as I haven't submitted enough question yet to embed images) is obviously taken from the Immediate Window when I was running the app.  I entered the steps in the exact order shown. Note that I set Application.DisplayAlerts = False and then checked the value immediately afterwords and it was True.

Very weird.  Is this a bug?

One last aside that is probably irrelevant; I was using .XLSB format because of the smaller footprint, much shorter load time and to get around PC setup issues with macros.  But I've switched back to .XLSX to simplify the experiment.

Comment: You can not set `DisplayAlerts` to false outside of a sub... this way the immediate window will never show the true value... but you can create a sub with `Stop` and test it again while the sub is at halt... it should now show false... but as soon as the sub ends, it will be true again...

Comment: MSDN: `If you set this property to False, Microsoft Excel sets this property to True when the code is finished, unless you are running cross-process code.` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839782.aspx

Comment: Also it should be wrapped inside a `EnableEvents = False`... then nothing should pop up as long as any sub is running...

Comment: I am setting to false within a sub and just used the imnmeidate window to display for ease of explanation.  I've read read about "cross process" but don't know exact how this is defined.  I set the value to false after displaying a message in Workbook_Open()

Comment: In short: as soon as no sub is running anymore (no vba code is in active processing) the value will be set to true again...

Comment: Sorry I hit carriage return twice and got kicked out of my comment...

I am setting to false within a sub and just used the immediate window to display for ease of explanation.  

I've read read about "cross process" but don't know exact how this is defined with context.  Your help there would be appreciated.

I set the value to false after displaying a message in Private Workbook_Open() and again inside of a sub invoked by selection of a combo box entry.

I also set the value to false in Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Should I change the private subs to public?

Comment: Assuming this 'save data?' dialog appears on close of the workbook. You can trick the workbook into thinking it's already been saved before exiting such as:   Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean) ThisWorkbook.Saved = true End Sub. Now if your macro manipulates a workbook object, you'd have to replace 'ThisWorkbook' with the workbook object instead.

Comment: @Kris B – I had had tried much elaborate solution (which didn’t work) but I thought what you suggested was simple and should work.  The code (below) didn’t work.  The “Do you want to save?” message displayed as before.
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Sheets("PERFORMANCE").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub

Comment: @Dirk Reichel – I also tried the code below based on what I understood you were saying:  
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheets("PERFORMANCE").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
The “Do you want to save” message did not display but there was a blank window instead (I see why but don't know what to do about it.)  I could right click with the blank app window and open the spreadsheet again.

Answer (score 3):

To clarify: the code temporarily halts after each single-step in the debugger, resulting in Excel setting it back to **True** while idle.  Here’s a way to verify this behavior:

1. In the VBE code-development window, open the Immediate window (Ctrl-G).
2. Temporarily insert the following code somewhere in your routine:

   Debug.Print "..."

   Application.DisplayAlerts = False

   Debug.Print "Application.DisplayAlerts: " & Application.DisplayAlerts

   Stop
3. Using the “**Set Next Statement**” tool (or Ctrl-F9), set the **Debug.Print "..."** statement to be the next one to execute.
4. Run the code form there by pressing F5 (**Continue**).
5. You should see this displayed on the Immediate window:

   ...

   Application.DisplayAlerts: False
6. Now, with the code stopped at the **Stop** statement, type “?Application.DisplayAlerts” in the Immediate window, and press the [Enter] key.  You will get:

   ?Application.DisplayAlerts

   True

   because Excel has reset it to **True** while the code is suspended.
7. Remove the experimental code.